# OWL - Multiple restriction to object property

Tags: rdf, owl, semantic-web, object-property

Consider this example of knowledge representation [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9ZGh.png).

Using OWL, is there a way to say that only the "derived from" property which connects "Lolita (Book)" and "Lolita (1962)" is correct, because "Vladimir Nabokov" is connected to both of them, respectively with "author of" and "written by"?

While, I want to assert that other case (where "derived from" connects "Lolita (Book)" and "Lolita (1997)") is wrong, because it does not have the previous conditions.

Comment: that needs SWRL. **but:** Neitrher OWL nor its rule extension SWRL is for constraint validation resp. correctness checks - they do just deductive reasoning, nothing more nothing less. In your case you should think and read about SHACL, ShEx etc. I think

Comment: Thank you for your answer! My question was more related to a method to express this type of information, rather than a validation strategy. I believe that SWRL is the solution!